# Cannot delete cookies that were set in JavaScript on the server

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, cookies

I am trying to write PHP code to delete all of the user cookies on my domain.

Here is what I got:

```
<?php
$domain = 'www.example.com';
$deleteExpiration = time() - 60*60*24*365*10; // 10 years ago
foreach (array_keys($_COOKIE) as $cookie) {
    setcookie($cookie, 0, $deleteExpiration, '/', $domain);
}
```

Running this code on http://www.example.com/delete_cookies.php deletes all cookies that were set on the server, but not cookies that were set in JavaScript.

I verified using the Firefox Cookies dialog that the problematic cookies are indeed from (path=/; domain=www.example.com). Using Live HTTP headers, I can see that the following header is sent:

```
Set-Cookie: CookieName=0; expires=Fri, 12-Mar-1999 19:36:15 GMT; path=/; domain=www.example.com
```

So I believe the setcookie command is working as expected. Firefox is just not honoring the request.

One additional thing that I noticed is that if I set a cookie with `domain=www.example.com` on the server, then it is listed in the Firefox cookie dialog with `domain=".www.example.com"`, but if I set the following cookie using JavaScript code then the leading dot is not added.

What am I doing wrong? How can I delete these cookies?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25967822/1642018

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->delete()`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L173) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had a similar issue and it was solved by just not passing the domain.

`setcookie($cookie, '', 1, '/');`

On a side note from [cookie_spec](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html) "*Setting the path to a higher-level value does not override other more specific path mappings. If there are multiple matches for a given cookie name, but with separate paths, all the matching cookies will be sent.*" So if you have same name cookies at different path locations you will have to delete each one.